# How to remove "Sync Issues", "Search Folders" and "Groups" tabs in Microsoft Outlook 365 desktop navigation pane?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I think the title explains the problem pretty well. In Outlook 365 desktop navigation pane you get some folders(or tabs) created for you and I want to get rid of them. Please take a look at [following screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQmwe.png). I want to remove everything in the red squares.

I have removed the majority of the unused folders using OutlookSpy. However, it seems outlook spy doesn't work for these folders. Any help would be appreciated, I have several email accounts and I want to be able to see all the folders without scrolling. The amount of space these folders waste is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/06945dab-274b-4f0e-a903-0c39a9b74353/how-to-hide-sync-issues-folder-and-other-system-folder-in-outlook-2010?forum=outlook) which talks about how to hide Sync Issues Folder.

It seemed that you have done a Ctrl +6 activates the “Folder list” option which in turn displays all hidden folder in the Navigation folder.

In addition, which also may be that you click the Folder in Navigation tab as
the following screenshot:

[image]

You can press Ctrl+1 to hide the sync issues or use MFCMAPI to delete it.
Here is [an article](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/delete-outlooks-default-folders/#:%7E:text=Tools%20%7C%20More%20Information-,Delete%20the%20Folder,-After%20downloading%20MFCMAPI) on how to use MFCMAPI to delete folders you can refer to.

However, Search folders and Groups are the features of Outlook, they don't seem to be able to be removed.

Comment: Hello, I am in mail view so I am not seeing hidden folders. Also, I checked the link you included in your answer and it seems that you can't hide any of the folders in my question as per comments of the article author article himself. Unfortunate.

Comment: Hi，I mean, according to my tests, when I click on the Folders, the screenshot you provided can be reproduced, and when I press ctrl+1, the sync issues is hidden. Besides, because the search folders is a vitural folder, which can not be deleted.Group is a function of 0365, so it cannot be deleted either.